# java Eclipse only see one method in class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class whigh had a single method "createChart" that worked as expected. I am now trying to add another method a copy of createChart, but Eclipse does not recognise it. Intellsenses see only the first method. There are no highlighted errors elsewhere.

I tested if I caould any otehr simple method - but none are recognised.

```
public class Histogram extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  public Histogram() {

  }



  public JFreeChart createChart(double[] v1) {
      //does stuff
      return chart;
  }

  public JFreeChart createChart2(double[] v1) {
      //does other stuff
      return chart;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are u testing it ?  It shoudl recognize there is some problem in your testing method.

Comment: What does `Eclipse doesn't recognize the method` mean..?

Comment: Have you tried building after writing the new method (make sure you don't have any other compile errors) then testing if it is recognised? Otherwise try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: @Alowaniak. Restarting Eclipse fixed it thank you

Answer (score 1):

there are missing semicolons:

```
public JFreeChart createChart(double[] v1) {
    //does stuff
    return chart; //here
}

public JFreeChart createChart2(double[] v1) {
    //does other stuff
    return chart; //and here
}
```

Comment: The semicolons are in code - just forgot them in the example.  createChart is recognised but createChart2 (which is an exact copy except for the name) is not

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems valid but Eclipse validator sometimes has weired behaviors. Try to save your file and close/open the filetab.

This this the whole code or could you paste the whole class with package and everything into your question?